# How I use order by (name) in this code to get result in asc order

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

How I use order by (name) in this code to get result in asc order?

This is the piece of code:

```
function getRecordByID($id)
    {
        $this->db->select($this->tbl_area_menu.'.*,'.$this->tbl_users.'.firstname as created_by,'.$this->tbl_page.'.name as page_name,'.$this->tbl_page.'.slug as page_slug,'.$this->tbl_page.'.template_directory,'.$this->tbl_directory.'.slug as directory_slug');

        $this->db->where($this->tbl_area_menu.'.id',$id);
        $this->db->join($this->tbl_users,$this->tbl_users.'.id = '.$this->tbl_area_menu.'.created_by','left');
        $this->db->join($this->tbl_page,$this->tbl_page.'.id = '.$this->tbl_area_menu.'.page_id','left');
        $this->db->join($this->tbl_directory,$this->tbl_directory.'.id = '.$this->tbl_page.'.template_directory','left');


        $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_area_menu);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        $record = $query->row();
        return $record;
    }
```

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: What *language* is this code? It's not SQL. And, if relevant, which *data-access* library are you using within that language? Please [edit] your question and add relevant tags.

Comment: There is no SQL in your question.

Comment: are you use laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html). If that is the case, after all the `join`s add [`$this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results)